# Is the set of all points, the probability of which is non-zero, always countable?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

Let $P$ be an arbitrary probability distribution on an arbitrary set $X$. Define $Y:=\{x\in X: P(x) > 0\}$. Is $Y$ always countable?

Moreover, given $a$ s.t. $0<a<1$, can we always find a partition $Y_1, ..., Y_N, Z_1, ..., Z_M$ of $X$ such that $Y_1, ..., Y_N$ are singletons, $P(Y_i) \ge a$ and $P(Z_j) \le a$? If so, can we find a specific partition such that $M+N$ can be linearly upper bounded by $a$?

Comment: $Y$ might be empty.  There would be nothing to count so is that countable?

Comment: @Henry. Yes. Just check the definition.

Comment: @Henry . Countable means "finite or countably infinite".

Answer (score 1):

You have to assume that every singleton set is measurable.

First part: The answer is  YES. If $x_1,x_2,..,x_k$ are points in the set $\{x: P(x) >\frac 1 n\}$ then $1 \geq P\{x_1,x_2,..,x_n\}= \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}  P(x_i)> \frac k n$ so $k \leq n$. Hence $\{x: P(x) >\frac 1 n\}$ is a finite set for each $n$ and the given set is the union of these sets as $n$ varies from $1$ to $\infty$.

The second part is not true in general. Consider a $P$ such that every singleton has measure $0$. If the claim is true then for every $\epsilon >0$ there must be at least one measurable set $Z$ with $P(Z) <\epsilon$. This is true in nice spaces but not in general.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Could you please take a look at the further question updated?

Comment: @Harvett I have edited my answer.

Comment: Both $N, M$ can be zero and $Z_j$ is also allowed to be a singleton.

Comment: One of them can be $0$. But $N+M > 0$.

Comment: In your example, $Y_1 = \{2\}, Z_1 = \{1\}$.

Comment: @Harvett I have added an answer for the second part.